# Create a modified own Com Object in the registry

Tags: windows, com, registry, guid, clsid

I want to modified the Internet Explorer CLSID element in the registry: (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} )

It is possible to copy this entry and replace the GUID and create a new alias?
Where can I defined a new alias?
(Later I want to open this Com Object in PowerShell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as an 'alias' for registry keys.  You can however create an entry in HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID, COM looks there first.  This would also limit the amount of damage you do to the machine and you'll have halfway decent odds of actually being able to write the key.

Comment: I copied the entry from the Internet Explorer and renamed it newname.Application. Now when I wants to used it in PowerShell ($ie = New-Object -ComObject newname.Application) nothing happened. I have tried both, 64 an 32 bit PowerShell.

Comment: Wrong copy, you have to copy the CLSID with all of its keys.